# Angular Auth Gaurds - rout to previous page

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular 9.

I have the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path:'login', component:LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'approval-list', component: ApprovalListComponent, canActivate: [ApprovalListGuard] },
    { path: 'edit-approval/:tripId', component: ApprovalListComponent }
];
```

As you can see, if a user enters on the `'approval-list'` url, they will be routed to the `ApprovalListGuard`.

**approval-list.guards**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApprovalListGuard implements CanActivate, CanLoad {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate() {
    return this.canLoad();
  }

  canLoad() {
    if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

This in turn will send the user to the login page (`'/login'`) `LoginComponent`.

This works as expected.

My question is, once the user routes to the `LoginComponent`, and logs in successfully, I would like them to continue the `'approval-list'` path to the `ApprovalListComponent`.

**login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: [''],
      password: ['']
    });
  }

  get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

  login() {
    this.authService.login(
      {
        username: this.f.username.value,
        password: this.f.password.value
      }
    )
    .subscribe(success => {
      if (success) {
        this.router.navigate(['/approval-list']);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This works, i.e. it routs to the `approval-list`. However, I don't want it to be hard-coded.  How do I set the route to the url before the guard sent it to `/login`?  For example, if I want it to get it working for `edit-approval`.

**Question**

How do I replace the following line without a hard-coded url:

```
this.router.navigate(['/approval-list']);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**In ApprovalListGuard**

```
this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { backUrl: '/approval-list' } });
```

Then, in the LoginComponent:

```
// Create an property to get the backUrl param on the url
get backUrl(): string | null {
  return this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('backUrl');
}

// After the success login
this.router.navigate([this.backUrl || '/defaultPath']);
```

The activatedRoute object must be injected (from @angular/router);

That's is the way I do in my projects.

Comment: If my url contains a parameter, how fo I get it? (e.g. `'edit-approval/:tripId'`). How do I get the `tripId` and pass it through?  I have tried to look at the `this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap` when in the `ApprovalEditGuard` to append to the url, but there are no parameters. (also `console.log(this.activateRoute.snapshot.params['tripId']);` is `undefined`)

Comment: I will try to make a sample on stackblitz, wait a minute.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a query string containing the previous page URL when you redirect to login page. Once login is successful you can navigate back the the URL passed inside the query string. this is the most common pattern that i have seen on websites.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.  When you say, create a query string, what do you mean?  Do you store the previous url somewhere and then retrieve it?